# TikZ: How to add fill in style of multiple arcs?

Tags: tikz-pgf, draw, fill, pattern

I want to visualize poured loose coarse soil.

---

**Minimum Working Example (MWE):**

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture} 
   \draw (0, 0) rectangle (4, 4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

I won't post a screenshot, because it is just a simple rectangle. :-)

How can I fill this rectangle with a pattern consisting of different arc lines? In `LibreCAD` this pattern is simply called "arcs".

[image: Screenshot of the desired pattern]

---

Any ideas on how to do so?

Comment: Do you have the code for one piece of the pattern? If so, you can either declare a pattern (faster compilation but harder to code and non-transformable) or just use `pic`s to fill the thing (longer compilation time but easier to do and transformable).

Comment: @marmot: Great idea! Could I get the code out of `LibreCAD` maybe?

Comment: Dunno, this is the first time I heard about LibreCAD.

Comment: I will say it is interesting, having both vertical, horizontal and diagonal regularity and no obvious joins.  Octagons?